# Solution of a Volterra integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the Volterra integral equation

$$y(x)=x-\int_0^x xt^2 y(t)\,dt$$

How do I solve it? Predicting $y$ using iteration is seeming difficult. Please help.

Comment: Does $x$ depend on $t$? I mean, can you push $x$ outside the integral, obtaining $$y(x) = x\left(1 - \int_0^x t^2 y(t) dt \right)?$$

Comment: Yes,you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start from this equation:
$$y(x) = x\left(1 - \int_0^x t^2 y(t) dt \right)$$

Differentiating both sides, we get:

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = \left(1 - \int_0^x t^2 y(t) dt \right) - x^3y(x).$$

Notice that:

$$y(x) = x\left(1 - \int_0^x t^2 y(t) dt \right) \Rightarrow \left(1 - \int_0^x t^2 y(t) dt \right) = \frac{y(x)}{x}.$$

Then:
$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = \frac{y(x)}{x} - x^3y(x) \Rightarrow \\y' = y\left(\frac{1}{x} - x^3\right).$$

Now, we can separate the variables:

$$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int \left(\frac{1}{x} - x^3\right)dx \Rightarrow \\
\log(y) = \log(x) - \frac{x^4}{4} + C \Rightarrow \\
y = e^{\log(x) - \frac{x^4}{4} + C} \Rightarrow\\
y = Ax e^{-\frac{x^4}{4}}.$$

Comment: Also,how do i find the arbitrary constant?

Comment: Generally, the constant is found by plugging the solution in the initial equation, and/or by imposing initial conditions.

Comment: I guess $A = 1$ (equivalently, $C=0$). You can find it by yourself and tell me if it is correct.

Comment: Yes you are right.thanks.